# Multiple Google Oauth2 Clients - Refresh Tokens revoked when user grants different Client access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm building a system where users may be required to grant access to 1 or more Google services (using the Oauth2 server flow).

For the first service they authorise, everything works perfectly - however, when they then authorise a second service (using a **different** client id & secret), the original refresh token from the first authorisation is invalidated.

Is this expected behaviour or I am doing something wrong somewhere?

I expect that by using multiple Client Ids & Secrets, I should be able to store multiple refresh tokens, once for each service granted access to - so both users and I can be in total control of what is shared and used where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client id + client secret + refresh token are a combination that is needed to gain access to a users data.

A refresh token can only be used with the client id and secret that were used to create it.

Each application should have only two client ids. One for test / development and the other for production.   You should be storing only one refresh token for a user which contains access to all of the scopes you require.

Comment: Thanks for your response - ideally I'd want users to be able to grant/revoke access incrementally
With one refresh token, they'd only be able to revoke the entire app rather than just one service - is that possible?

Comment: You can use the revoke endpoint to revoke the users consent for your app.  its an all or nothing there is no way to remove granted scopes once they have been granted.  I think your making more work for yourself if you do this with two clients.